# Compare rows in a groupbydataframe for a column containing negative values

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this below

df_row (please see attached)

```
TRADING_DATE    INSTRUMENT  INSTRUMENT_ID   PRICE   VENUE   PRICE_NOTATION
2019-08-02      ISIN        EZ8115792R14     -0.372 BMTF    PERC
2019-08-02      ISIN        EZ8115792R14     -0.372 BMTF    PERC
2019-08-02      ISIN        EZCT8G280NZ1    -0.381  BMTF    PERC
2019-08-02      ISIN        EZCT8G280NZ1    -0.381  BMTF    PERC
```

I group this dataframe by Transaction id: 
`g1 = df_row.groupby('TRANSACTION_ID')`

Now I would like to compare both the rows under each group for equality with this :

```
    for group in g1:
         df_group = group[1]
         row1 = df_group.iloc[0,1:37]
         row2 = df_group.iloc[1,1:37] 
         if (row1 == row2) is True:
             df_group['RESULTS'] = 'Matched'
         else:
             df_output = row1 ==row2
             vals = [i for i,j in df_output.items() if j== False]
             df_group['RESULTS'] = 'Failed Match !'
             df_group['MISMATCHED_COLUMNS'] = ', '.join(vals)
```

Issues :
Question 1 : 
For df_row , group with transaction _id - EZ8115792R14  returns FALSE for PRICE column (has negative values of -0.372 in both rows under this group)
whereas for df_row , group with transaction id - EZCT8G280NZ1 returns TRUE for PRICE Column (has negative value of -0.381 in both rows of this group)
What is the reason of this inconsistency in comparison of negative values via row1== row2 ?
Any suggestions how to handle this case?

Question 2 : 
I get a warning when I run the code below , I understand why this warning is coming but not sure of the implementation for removing this warning.
excel_compare.py:78: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: sample data is in the question above , pls see df_row .(second line from top)